# Can my app be rejected by Apple if I changed an UISeachBar background?

Tags: uisearchbar, appstore-approval

Will my app be rejected by Apple if I changed an UISearchBar background to be transparent?

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'private' APIs, or modify controls when Apple documentation says not to, then Apple may indeed reject your App. Possibly during initial review, or at a later date.

There is also the possibility that the API may change or be removed, without warning, causing your App to crash.

However, there are Apps in the App Store that clearly do use private APIs, and have been approved, but it's a risk you take.  If that concerns you, don't do it.

Comment: I'm not using any API, just 4 lines of code written on my own.

Comment: If you're only modifying properties defined here http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html and not contravening any restrictions stated by Apple, then you're OK.  However, if you're using something like setAlpha, and the documentation says not to, you're effectively using a private API.

Comment: Ok. Got the API thing. Regarding the documentation saying not to change. It doesn't say neither I can or can't. So?

Comment: If it doesn't say you can't, then you can :-)   I use the Mail Composer dialog, and it explicitly says it shouldn't be customized, even though it works if you do :-/  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200